# gdb-qemu : can't put break point on kernel function ( kernel 4.10.0-35)

Tags: 16.04, kernel, gdb

I am trying to debug the Ubuntu kernel using KDB + qemu. However, I am not able to debug it. Following is the error I am getting. Can someone help?

Starting QEMU:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -s -machine type=pc,accel=kvm -cpu host -nographic  -k de -usb -m 2048  -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3389-:22  ubuntu16.04.qcow2
```

Starting Debugger:

```
sudo gdb ./debian/build/build-generic/vmlinux -iex 'add-auto-load-safe-path .'  -ex 'target remote localhost:1234'
```

Setting break point:

```
gdb-peda$ b printk
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff811ad8f3: file /home/test/ubuntu/linux-hwe-4.10.0/kernel/printk/printk.c, line 1864.
gdb-peda$ c
Continuing.
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff811ad8f3
Command aborted.
gdb-peda$  disassemble printk
Dump of assembler code for function printk:
   0xffffffff811ad8f3 <+0>: Cannot access memory at address
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have disabled [**KASLR**](https://lwn.net/Articles/569635/) (Kernel address space layout randomization) or use **add-symbol-file** to add kernel symbol file instead of file, so that you can manually specify .text .data and .bss.

> *KASLR make exploits harder by placing various objects at random, rather than fixed, addresses.*

**To disable KASLR**, append "nokaslr" parameter to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` file and do update-grub.
e.g.

```
$ grep "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nokaslr"
$ update-grub && reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

As @vg598 said it's about KASLR, but using update-grub you will update everything including KGDB options in the grub.cfg file.

A better approach is to manually modify /boot/grub/grub.conf adding the 'nokaslr' flag before or after the KGDB options.

Answer (score 0):

Like avg598 said, Kernel address space randomization [KASLR](https://lwn.net/Articles/569635/) needs to be disabled for debugging.

Quick solution:

- Add `nokaslr` to the Linux bootline. Modern bootloaders allow transient changes to be done directly in the bootloader menu. Activating this in a *transient* manner only during the debugging session is better for your system's cyber security. (E.g. [Ubuntu Wiki on Kernel Boot Parameters, section "Temporarily Add a Kernel Boot Parameter for Testing"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters#Temporarily_Add_a_Kernel_Boot_Parameter_for_Testing))

Alternative:

- Disable `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE` in the kernel configuration and rebuild the kernel. (E.g. if you're using a special kernel `.config` for debugging anyway, this might be more convenient than the kernel bootline.)